# How do I serve an Image to client from Azure storage using Node API?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I use this function from azure/storage-blob package to retrive my file from Azure but how can I serve it to client using express API?

```
async function getData(container = 'newcontainer1646492958419', fileName = "splashscreen_image.png") {
      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
    
      const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
      const resp = await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
      return resp
    }
    
    async function streamToString(readableStream) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks = [];
        readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
          chunks.push(data.toString());
        });
        readableStream.on("end", () => {
          resolve(chunks.join(""));
        });
        readableStream.on("error", reject);
      });
    }
```

Comment: is this a passthrough? are you sure you want to put this entire file in memory?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use `pipe` to directly stream the blob content to your http `response` object, see the example [here](https://williamandrewgriffin.com/how-to-download-from-azure-blob-storage-with-streams-using-express/)

Comment: You also should ensure the right `mime` type or `content-type` are set on your image files/blobs that are stored in your blob container.

Comment: Could you please let us know ,If you are able to fetch the data from your blob storage.